# How to display different Parse.com classes using same table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I have like six classes at my Parse.com app in their website. I have one table view controller where i'd like to show the items of those classes, but I want a way to tell the table view controller which parse class to show. How can I achieve that? 
I tried setting an NSString object from another view controller and setting self.parseClassName in initWithCoder method to that object, but didn't work.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by referring to topViewController that is inside a navigationViewController, and setting a string variable in it. Something like this:

```
 UINavigationController *navCtrl = [segue destinationViewController];
    TableViewController *tableVC =  (TableViewController *) navCtrl.topViewController;
    tableVC.pClass = @"Phones"; //pClass is an NSString in the tableVC class
```

Then in the queryForTable method i just used that

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
```

{

```
PFQuery *query;
if(_pClass != nil){
    query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:_pClass];
} 

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

return query;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Unless the classes are related via pointers with Pointer columns so that they could be included in the result set via a relation, this wouldn't be possible with a PFTableViewController. You would have to use a regular UITableViewController and then perform multiple queries for each class and then you could use a conditional in your `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method.

Comment: for convenient i'm using PFQueryTableViewController for my class, you're suggestion sounds like good idea, i'll try that. Thank you

Comment: There is no right way to accomplish this @fullMoon , however, this is probably the way you shouldn't go, this sounds like it will create more work than necessary. And you don't have to use a regular `UITableViewController` just simply put a NSString property in your header and pass a string to that. Then load your class name from that property

Comment: That would work so long as only one class is displayed at a time. However if @fullMoon's intent is to show > 1 class out of the 6 in one table view controller than multiple classes would still need to be queried. A `PFTableViewController` cannot query and populate a table with more than one class unless there are pointers.

Comment: more than one class isn't the goal @Aaron OP is just asking how to load 1 of those 6 based on a condition, a condition you can fulfill prior to segueing

Comment: @soulshined, yes that what I wanted, but I have to assign a valid class name to "self.parseClassName" in initWithCoder method in table view controller, and initWithCoder method is called very early even before the NSString property gets the value from a segue.  Aron's suggestion to not to use PFQueryTableViewController could be valid idk but i'm still trying to figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: did you figure it out @fullMoon